# MySQL return static strings

Tags: php, mysql, static

I have a CMS that requires a SQL query to return options/values for a dropdown... typically it returns the rows from the table in the SQL query and fills in the dropdown options. Sometimes I just want to have two static options in the dropdown and do not want to create a whole table to manage those two unchanging items.

My questions is: Is there a MySQL query that will not query a table but will just return some static results as if it were querying a table?

Ideally I would like something similar to this (but static):

```
SELECT value FROM `fake_table`
```

And return the following:

```
value
//////////////
Option One
Option Two
Option Three
Etc...
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If they're static values, why not just hard-code them into your html? Then use the database to fill in the subsequent `<option>`'s.

Comment: check if the query result is empty and return a default behaviour

Comment: Use hard-coded values, and save yourself the overheads of a spurious MySQL query.

Comment: Although the answer below works great, I have created the options in a hardcoded array (since that is better practice).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
select 'Option One' as Value
union
select 'Option Two' as Value
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the syntax to select a constant value is the same in MySQL as MSSQL:

```
SELECT 'fake_value_1' AS value, 1 AS sort
UNION ALL
SELECT 'fake_value_2', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT value, 3 FROM table
ORDER BY sort, value
```

The `sort` column ensures the fake values always appear at the beginning of the result set, but that the actual values are sorted by their value.

**Note** that UNION ALL (as opposed to UNION) will not attempt to eliminate duplicates when it combines resultsets. This is legitimate assuming your static values won't duplicate any values in the actual table - this is worth keeping in mind, as UNION ALL has slightly better performance (unlikely to make a difference in this case, but a good general rule).

**Also Note:** As @Marc B mentions in the comments, it may be better separation of concerns to put the static values in your presentation layer, instead of putting that logic in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a **string** and **two columns** as a single column:

```
SELECT CONCAT('example string', column1, column2) AS combined FROM table;
```